# Tips on using Apache .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, web-services

First off, there is a plethora of great material on .htaccess on SO.  However, some of it is advanced and it mostly spread across multiple questions.  Today I found a tutorial with a number of good tips, which will be in an answer.

Community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial at [JavaScriptKit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml) covers the following topics
each with a brief example:

- Error Documents
- Password protection
- Enabling SSI via htaccess
- Blocking users by IP
- Blocking users/ sites by referrer
- Blocking bad bots and site rippers (aka offline browsers)
- Change your default directory page
- Redirects
- Prevent viewing of htaccess
- Adding MIME types
- Preventing hot linking of your images and other file types
- Preventing directory listing

Answer (score 0):

An [advanced tutorial on mod_rewrite](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html), a commonly used feature of .htaccess files:

Answer (score 0):

Some different methods for [preventing hotlinking](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/anti-hotlinking-mod_rewrite.html) with mod_rewrite: